# Convert List into Dictionary and Convert its values and keys to integer with List Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose we have a list of list called `A`:

```
A = [['1', '200'], ['2', '450'], ['3', '300']]
```

What I want to do are convert list of lists above into a dictionary with first element as key and second as value, and after that I want to make both of keys and values converted to integer.

So it will be as follows:

```
A = {1: 200, 
     2: 450,
     3: 300}
```

With all keys and values are integer.

I tried  list comprehension for this:

```
A = dict(zip(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in row for row in A)
```

Got error on it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Comment: Do include error messages for things that have an error in it.

Comment: thanks for your correction @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `zip()` here, just drop that, and you can loop directly over `A` and unpack into `a` and `b`:

```
A = dict((int(a), int(b)) for a, b in A)
```

That's a *generator expression* passing tuples to the `dict()` callable.

If you can, you want to use a dictionary comprehension instead; that's available in Python 2.7 and newer (including all Python 3.x releases):

```
A = {int(a): int(b) for a, b in A}
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = [['1', '200'], ['2', '450'], ['3', '300']]
>>> dict((int(a), int(b)) for a, b in A)
{1: 200, 2: 450, 3: 300}
>>> {int(a): int(b) for a, b in A}
{1: 200, 2: 450, 3: 300}
```

Comment: Yap, this is what I  looking for, Thanks

Comment: dammit my page didn't show this answer while i post mine :p... cheers, i always forgot that list comprehension can use more than one variable to access its members, so i always automatically use a single var like `[i for i in mylist]`...

Comment: hey, how about if the `A` was a semicolon-comma-separated value string such as `A = "1, 200; 2, 450; 3, 300"` ? how to split it and convert it to `int` ?

Comment: @JONPANTAU: where did the data start from, a file? Consider using the `csv` module to at least handle the `;` splitting. The remainder is just further text processing; `dict([int(v) for v in pair.split(',')] for pair in A.split(';'))` would handle your sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [['1', '200'],['2', '450'],['3','300']]
B_dict = {int(i[0]): int(i[1]) for i in A}
```

Comment: Yep, its similar with one before, the difference is yours create a new variable.

Comment: @JONPANTAU yes, you can overwrite `A`, like so `A = {int(i[0]: int(i[1]) for i in A}`. i just have a habit of not overwriting raw data, handy when you need to preserve original data source, and cleaner when there's a lot of mutable iterations involved in the script.